Convert Output Date to Another Format
Batch code: echo %date%, the Output: 03/04/2024.
I need to convert the output to: April 03,2024
In Powershell i can do this with: date -f 'MMMM dd,yyyy'
What code i need to do this in pure Batch ?
Not calling Powershell

This .bat file will extract the date parts :
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "months= 1:Jan 2:Feb 3:Mar 4:Apr 5:May 6:Jun 7:Jul 8:Aug 9:Sep 10:Oct 11:Nov 12:Dec"

for /f "skip=1 tokens=1,2,3" %%A in (
  '"wmic path win32_localtime get day, month, year"'
) do if Not "%%B" == "" for /f %%M in ("!months:* %%B:=!") do (
    set "month=%%M"
    set "year=%%C"
    set "day=%%A"
)

echo day=!day! month=!month! year=!year!


I often find myself wanting to have the current date and/or time available within a batch file, broken down into its individual components. A typical example is when I want to create an output file each day, but I want the file to be unique, so it doesn't step on the output file from yesterday.
Here's a sample batch file from Rob van der Woude showing how to do this. By parsing the tokens from the "prompt $D $T" piece, in combination with the tokens from the second line of output from the "date" command, this will handle any date format (such as mm-dd-yy, dd-mm-yy, and so forth). It puts the seven components of the date and time (day of week, month, day, year, hour, minute, and second) in seven variables (dow, mm, dd, yy, hh, min, and ss). Now you can do whatever you want with them (within the setlocal/endlocal block, of course).
@echo off

rem Create the date and time elements.
setlocal
For /f "tokens=1-7 delims=:./-, " %%i in ('echo exit^|cmd /q /k"prompt $D $T"') do (
    For /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/-,() skip=1" %%a in ('echo.^|date') do (
        set dow=%%i
        set %%a=%%j
        set %%b=%%k
        set %%c=%%l
        set hh=%%m
        set min=%%n
        set ss=%%o
    )
)

rem Uncomment the next line for debugging the date and time elements.
rem For %%i in (dow dd mm yy hh min ss) do set %%i

rem Example usage patterns:
If NOT "%dow%" == "Sun" Echo It's not Sunday.

echo Hello, world! > TestFile_%yy%%mm%%dd%_%hh%%min%%ss%.txt

pause
endlocal

That should give you the building blocks to do almost everything you want. The only remaining piece is to get the full month name of "April". I'll keep working on that.

this is cmd startup text on my PC "Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.3758]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Clink v0.4.9 [git:2fd2c2] Copyright (c) 2012-2016 Martin Ridgers
http://mridgers.github.io/clink"

Sorry. You asked "What code I need to do this in pure Batch?" Isn't Clink a modification to the Cmd.exe, so your environment isn't really "pure". If I can get the long month name added, I'll leave the answer in case it helps others. And I'll add a note about Clink to the answer. Thanks for the feedback.

I mean pure batch is not calling powershell, because calling it easy but sometimes make the output slow. Maybe you need to edit the code to fix any situations. Thaxs

After studying your code. just need add /d after cmd to Disable execution of AutoRun commands from registry. In this case, skip clink autorun message... "cmd /d /q /k"

Based on harrymc answer...
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set months=01:Jan 02:Feb 03:Mar 04:Apr 05:May 06:Jun 07:Jul 08:Aug 09:Sep 10:Oct 11:Nov 12:Dec
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/-: " %%A in ("%date%"
) do for /f %%M in ("!months:* %%B:=!"
) do set month=%%M& set year=%%C& set day=%%A

echo before %date%
echo after  !month! !day!,!year!
pause 

Output:
before 05/04/2024
after  Apr 05,2024

